Has this limit of this particular infinite series been documented anywhere? Is it known by chance?
$$\lim_{k\to\infty} \sum_{n=0}^{2k+1} (-1)^n \frac{2n}{2n+1} = -\frac{\pi}{4}$$
(By the way, I do not have any sort of proof for this equality, if it even holds, because I was simply tinkering with a calculator. Sorry if that's naive of me to do.)

Do you really need to use the upper evaluation limit $2 k+1$ instead of just $k$?

@StevenClark According to Mathematica the even and odd partial sums converge to different limits, so restricting to one or the other is indeed needed.

First, note that $2n/(2n+1)\to 1\neq 0$ as $n\to \infty$ and thus $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n 2n}{2n+1}$ is a divergent series. So we do have to proceed carefully to obtain a convergent series.
Consider for instance the sum up to $2k+1$ (an odd partial sum). As $\frac{2n}{2n+1}=1-\frac{1}{2n+1}$, we have
$$\sum_{n=0}^{2k+1}(-1)^n -\sum_{n=0}^{2k+1}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}$$
with the first sum vanishing identically. Since $1/(2n+1)\to 0$  monotonically as $n\to\infty$, the latter series converges according to the alternating series test; indeed, aside from the minus sign this is just Leibniz's formula for $\pi/4$. Hence the odd partial sums converge to $-\pi/4$ as indicated.
In contrast, suppose we sum up to $2k$ instead (an even partial sum). Discarding the $n=0$ term which vanishes, the same splitting as above yields $$\sum_{n=1}^{2k}(-1)^n -\sum_{n=1}^{2k+1}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}$$
The first sum again vanishes identically, but now the second sum begins at $n=1$. Hence we have Leibniz's formula with the first term dropped. So the even partial sums instead converge to $1-\pi/4$, in agreement with the earlier diagnosis that the initial series is divergent.

For your curiosity.
The Lerch transcendent function write
$$\Phi(z, s, \alpha) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac { z^n} {(n+\alpha)^s}$$ So, since you know the limit when $k\to \infty$
$$S_k=\sum_{n=0}^{2k+1}(-1)^n{2n\over2n+1}=-\frac \pi 4+\frac{1}{2} \Phi \left(-1,1,2
   k+\frac{5}{2}\right)$$ The asymptotics of this function seems to be complicated but a good approxiamation could be
$$S_k=-\frac \pi 4+\frac{1}{2}\Bigg(\frac{1}{4 k}-\frac{1}{2 k^2}+\frac{1}{4 k^3}+
O\left(\frac{1}{k^4}\right)\Bigg)$$

$$
S_k  \sim  - \frac{\pi }{4} + \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{m = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{E_{2m} }}{{4^{2m + 1} }}\frac{1}{{(k + 1)^{2m + 1} }}}
$$ where $E_m$ are the Euler numbers.

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{2k+1}(-1)^n{2n\over2n+1}=\sum_1\left(-{2n\over2n+1}+{2n+2\over2n+3}\right)=\sum_1\left(-1+{1\over2n+1}+1-{1\over2n+3}\right)
$$
$$={1\over3}-{1\over5}+{1\over7}-{1\over9}+\dotsb
$$
and from there it's well-known and easy to compute. (You have to be a little careful at the end, since there is a $-1+$ term without a balancing $+1-$ term).

Why do your subsequent series start at $n=1$?

@Semi, the term with $n=0$ is zero, so who needs it?

The $n=0$ term in the original series is, sure, but the $n=1$ term isn't. And since you're regrouping by pairs, that one does matter.

In a comment on the question above (which has now been deleted) you originally indicated $$\frac{2 n}{2 n+1}-\frac{2 (n+1)}{2 (n+1)+1}=\frac{2 n}{2 n+1}-\frac{2 n+2}{2 n+3}=-\frac{2}{(2 n+1) (2 n+3)}$$ which I interpret as a term for even $n$ plus the subsequent term for odd $n$. So evaluating the sum of this pair term for even values of $n$ (i.e. $n=2 m$) leads to $$\lim\limits_{k\to\infty} \left(\sum_{n=0}^{2k+1} \frac{(-1)^n, 2 n}{2 n+1}\right)=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty} \left(\sum\limits_{m=0}^k -\frac{2}{(4 m+1) (4 m+3)}\right)=-\frac{\pi }{4}.$$ Is this not correct?

@Semi, I don't catch your drift. True, the $n=1$ term isn't zero, so I keep it. If the original series was $a+b+c+d+e+\dotsb$, with $a=0$, my rewrite is just $(b+c)+(d+e)+\dotsb$.

@Steven, could be. I deleted my comment because I didn't catch the need for the $4m+1$ and the $4m+3$ in the denominator, and once I saw it I didn't see how to get from there to anything like $\pi/4$.

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n 2n}{2n+1}$ is a divergent series, so that grouping is not trivial. Indeed, if you group in pairs like your answer indicates, you instead have $$\left(0-\frac23\right)+\left(\frac45-\frac67\right)+\cdots=\left(1-\frac13\right)+\left(-\frac15+\frac17\right)+\cdots=-\frac{\pi}{4}$$

@Semi, I don't look at the infinite series, only at the finite summation. In the original, this has an even number of terms ($2k+2$, to be exact). I drop the first term (which is zero), then pair the 2nd with the 3rd, the 4th with the 5th, and so on. This leaves one unpaired term at the far end, to which I call attention in the parenthetical bit of my answer.

Mathematica and WolframAlpha both indicate $$\sum\limits_{m=0}^{\infty } -\frac{2}{(4 m+1) (4 m+3)}=-\frac{\pi }{4}.$$

@Steven, I don't doubt it, but does either one give a proof?

WolframAlpha doesn't spell out a proof, but gives the hint $$-\frac{\pi }{4}=-\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{2 k+1}\tag{1}$$ which I believe can be shown to be equivalent to $$-\frac{\pi}{4}=-\sum\limits_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{2}{(4 m+1) (4 m+3)}\tag{2}$$ using your approach of combining pairs of even and odd terms.

Formula (1) above is equivalent to $$-\frac{\pi }{4}=\sum {k=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^k}{2 k-1}\tag{3}$$ and Mathematica indicates $$\sum\limits{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{(2 k-1)^s}=4^{-s} \left(\zeta \left(s,\frac{3}{4}\right)-\zeta \left(s,\frac{1}{4}\right)\right)\tag{4}$$ which I belive is valid for $\Re(s)>0$, and Mathematica also indicates $$\underset{s\to 1}{\text{lim}} \left(4^{-s} \left(\zeta\left(s,\frac{3}{4}\right)-\zeta\left(s,\frac{1}{4}\right)\right)\right)=-\frac{\pi}{4}\tag{5}$$ which is consistent with the question conjecture.
